# Placing an image somewhere in the UI

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I place an image above my searchbar? I tried placing an Align widget with the image and inside the BoxDecoration of the Container but nothing shows up.

The goal is to place it like in this tutorial:
[image]

The tutorial says:
P.P.S. — The fading text and image are just Positioned the same way as SearchBar. They’re both placed inside AnimatedOpacity and the opacity param is based on the shrinkOffset. If shrinkOffset is more than a specific value, then opacity = 0.

but I cannot figure out how to do that.

https://medium.com/flutter-community/custom-shaped-appbar-as-seen-in-the-bunny-search-app-6312d067485c

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  child: ClipPath(
                      clipper: BackgroundWaveClipper(),
                      child: Container(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.1,
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [
                               Color.fromARGB(255, 132, 143, 240),
                               Color.fromARGB(255, 151, 238, 212)

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                  child: SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 32,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: textController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        focusColor: const Color(0xFFFACCCC),
                        focusedBorder: _border(const Color(0xFFFACCCC)),
                        border: _border(const Color(0xFFF2F2F7)),
                        enabledBorder: _border(const Color(0xFFF2F2F7)),
                        hintText: 'Breed search...',
                        contentPadding:
                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                filter = '';
                                textController.clear();
                              });
                            },
                            icon: Icon(Icons.clear)),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(
                          Icons.search,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          filter = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Is that image always fixed like that?

Comment: I guess so, the wave decoration is made with the class ClipPath. I have already done it exactly as in the tutorial but I could not get the image done.

Answer (score 0):

It's as the the tutorial say, wrap your Text and Image with an AnimatedOpacity and make adjustment based on shrinkOffset

```
Stack(
  children: [
    const ClipPath(),
    // add a new Positioned widget for Text and Image here
    Positioned( 
      top: ,   //
      left: ,  // adjust these to your liking for the positioned of the Text and Image
      right: , //
      child: AnimatedOpacity( // add AnimatedOpacity
        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
        curve: Curves.easeIn,
        opacity: shrinkOffset > 50 ? 0 : 1, // adjust opacity based on shrinkOffset
        child: SizedBox(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Row( // This is how I would do the Text and Image
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
                Text("Let's find\nCruelty-free brand"),
                Image.asset("your image here ( bunny )")
              ],
            )),
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
      left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
      child: const TextFormField(),
    )
  ],
)
```